# jquery returns same value in price calculation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to extract the data I pulled from the database. All buttons are working. The price is coming. But when I make a new query, it draws from the price of the product, not from the current price, and it distorts the price. I would be glad if you help.

```js
    Number.prototype.formatMoney = function (fractionDigits, decimal, separator) {
        fractionDigits = isNaN(fractionDigits = Math.abs(fractionDigits)) ? 2 : fractionDigits;

        decimal = typeof (decimal) === "undefined" ? "." : decimal;

        separator = typeof (separator) === "undefined" ? "," : separator;

        var number = this;

        var neg = number < 0 ? "-" : "";

        var wholePart = parseInt(number = Math.abs(+number || 0).toFixed(fractionDigits)) + "";

        var separtorIndex = (separtorIndex = wholePart.length) > 3 ? separtorIndex % 3 : 0;

        return neg +

            (separtorIndex ? wholePart.substr(0, separtorIndex) + separator : "") +

            wholePart.substr(separtorIndex).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + separator) +

            (fractionDigits ? decimal + Math.abs(number - wholePart).toFixed(fractionDigits).slice(2) : "");

    };
    function PriceCalculator(product_price, featured_price) {
        var product_money =   product_price;
        var money_to_fall =   featured_price;
        var money = product_money + money_to_fall;
        var result=  Number(money).formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=result;
    }
```

```html
<div id="form_step_1">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="talepler mb-3">
  <h4>GB</h4>
  <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-1"
             name="1"
             value="features-value-1"
             data-money="-300"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator(2500, -300)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-1">16GB</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-2"
             name="1"
             value="features-value-2"
             data-money="-200"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator(2500, -200)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-2">32GB</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-3"
             name="1"
             value="features-value-3"
             data-money="-50"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator(2500, -50)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-3">64GB</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <h4>DISPLAY</h4>
  <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-1"
             name="2"
             value="features-value-1"
             data-money="0"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator(2500, 0)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-1">Durable</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-2"
             name="2"
             value="features-value-2"
             data-money="-1500"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator(2500, -1500)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-2">Broken</label>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; right: 0px;">
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px"><strong>Pre-bid price:</strong> <div style="display: inline-block" id="money">Not calculated</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see the error from the code above. First choose 16GB, then choose durable, look at the price, then choose 16gb again, you will see the price change and you will understand that the durable one does not work.

Comment: I may be miss understanding here but isnt that simply because your not storing the value and then comparing it when you make any selection and thus it just reset based off the values passed to the function call. SHould you not store the value one each item and then upon subsequent clicks retrieve this value and subtract or add or whatever to calculate a new value based on the new selection?

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct. But I don't know how to do it as I am new to javascript. @Patrick Hume

Comment: so sorry for the late reply only just saw your comment I assume you are all ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we first need to improve the logic of your code.
First of all we create an object who will hold the value of each attribute of your PC

```
    const values = {
      gb: null,
      display: null,
    }
```

then, we remove your formatMoney function, since javascript already has the
built-in number.toLocaleString method to generate the formated number.

```
Number(total).toLocaleString("pt-BR",{minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
```

At last, we update your PriceCalculator function, which will be used to control each value and calculate the result, then we change the calls to match the logic. I.E.:

```
// Here we change the value of the display to 2500, this value will be added to the negative value of the GB which will generate the expected result.
onclick="PriceCalculator('display', 2500)"
```

```js
const values = {
  gb: null,
  display: null,
}

function PriceCalculator(label, newPrice) {
  values[label] = newPrice;
  if(values.gb != null && values.display != null){
    var total = values.gb + values.display;
    var result =  Number(total).toLocaleString("pt-BR",{minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=result;
  }    
}
```

```html
<div id="form_step_1">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="talepler mb-3">
  <h4>GB</h4>
  <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-1"
             name="1"
             value="features-value-1"
             data-money="-300"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator('gb', -300)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-1">16GB</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-2"
             name="1"
             value="features-value-2"
             data-money="-200"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator('gb', -200)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-2">32GB</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-3"
             name="1"
             value="features-value-3"
             data-money="-50"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator('gb', -50)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-3">64GB</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <h4>DISPLAY</h4>
  <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-1"
             name="2"
             value="features-value-1"
             data-money="0"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator('display', 2500)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-1">Durable</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="inputs" type="radio"
             id="features-2"
             name="2"
             value="features-value-2"
             data-money="-1500"
             data-product-money="2500"
              onclick="PriceCalculator('display', 1500)"
        >
        <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="features-2">Broken</label>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; right: 0px;">
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px"><strong>Pre-bid price:</strong> <div style="display: inline-block" id="money">Not calculated</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is right. It's working. But I am getting my data with php using foreach method. So these memory and screen loops are coming from the database and could be more. Is there an automatic method for this?